# Checking to see whether a string has certain characters in alphabetical order

Tags: java, string, alphabetical-sort

I have to check a word/phrase and say whether the vowels in it are in alphabetical or reverse alphabetical order.
Im so close to getting it. Its just the final bit comparing the numbers in the array, to see whether or not they are in descending order etc. I know I have to make a nested for loop but Im not sure exactly how to do it. Thanks for the help.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{


    String result = "", result2="";                                 
    String userInput = "aeiou";
    int [] array = new int[userInput.length()];


    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i) 
    {

        char c = replace.charAt( i );
        int j = (int) c;
        array[i] = j;

        //printing unicode symbols (only for testing)
        result2 += array[i] +",";
        System.out.println(j);
    }

    boolean sequence = false;
    for(int i = 0; i <array.length-1 && !sequence; i++)
    {
        for(int x =i+1; x<array.length; x++)
        {
            //Here I am checking to see whether or not they are in alphabetical order
            if(array[i] < array[x])
            sequence = true;
            if(sequence == true)
                result = "The vowels are  in  alphabetical order";
            else
                result = "The vowels are not in alphabetical order";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation?  That's really painful to read.

Comment: The problem is I cant check whether the array is in descedning or accending sequence

Comment: how about the upper/lower case? `Aa` is same as `aA` ?

Comment: @user2079139: I rollback your question, since the new question totally changes the meaning of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `replaceAll()`, I assume you can also use `matches()` (`replace` is the variable that contains the string after you replace everything but the vowels):

```
boolean isAscending = replace.matches("a*e*i*o*u*");
boolean isDescending = replace.matches("u*o*i*e*a*");
```

Well, there are some special cases here that doesn't seem to be considered in your code:

- String in `replace` variable is empty (no vowel)
- Only contains one vowel being repeated (e.g. `pool` --> `oo`)

In both cases above, `isAscending` and `isDescending` will both be `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the help man you basically cut my method down like crazy... I have spent the day trying to do this and I thought by changing the string to unicode then checking it would work :)

Comment: @user2079139: There are some comment about upper/lower case - which can be fixed by converting the user input to upper or lower case before replacement, or make the replacement case-insensitive by adding `(?i)`

Comment: @nhahtdh if he does case-insensitive it is ok. but if case does matter. e.g. aA = ascending, Aa=descending. your regex would be slightly changed. anyway good answer! +1

Comment: @user2079139 if the answer is helpful to you even solved your problem, please accept the answer. that is the way you say thank you here.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    String input = "abc";
    char[] a = input.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(a);
    if (input.equals(sb.toString())) {
        System.out.println("ascending");
    } else if (input.equals(sb.reverse().toString())) {
        System.out.println("descending");
    } else {
        System.out.println("unsorted");
    }
```